# Perfmon not showing recently added databases

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, perfmon

Problem: I have a production server ( 64-bit Windows server 2003 R2 ), when i try to add Sql:Databases counter in the perfmon, it does not show me the recently added databases to select from.

Addition Info: Now i had the same problem on another server which is my standby server. In this case i re-build the perfmon counters and restarted the sql service and the database listing in perfmon was refreshed and correct.

But the server in question is production box and i cannot re-start the sql service on it.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the latest service packs, etc? I just tried this on one of our servers (Windows 2003 R2, x32, SQL Server Express 2005 latest) and it worked fine.

Otherwise, try (from the command line):

```
wmiadap /clearadap
wmiadap /resyncperf
wmiadap /f
net stop winmgmt
net start winmgmt
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you capturing the Perfmon data to CSV files?

If so then you can't add new objects on the fly.